# JBoss WildFly 11, Hibernate ORM 5.2, OGM 5.3 and MongoDB - OgmIntegrator not found

Tags: hibernate-ogm, wildfly-11, hibernate-jpa

Progressing slowly through trying to get Hibernate ORM 5.2 working with OGM 5.3 so I can use JPA with MongoDB.

To remove the JNDI look-up error, referenced in the OGM FAQs:

> When using Hibernate OGM on top of WildFly, I’m getting a
>   JndiException. What’s wrong? In case you’re are seeing a JndiException
>   saying "Unable to lookup JNDI name [---PlaceHolderDSForOGM---]", your
>   application likely cannot access the application server module(s) of
>   Hibernate OGM.
>
> To change this, add the following line to the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
>   file of your archive (adapt it to match your chosen datastore):
>
> Dependencies: org.hibernate:ogm services, org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb
>   services Alternatively, you can configure this via the descriptor
>   jboss-deployment-structure.xml. See the reference guide to learn more.

I created: jboss-deployment-structure.xml

containing:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.3" services="export" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb" slot="5.3" services="export" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now when I try to deploy my EAR through the WildFly 11 console I get:

> 17:58:42,921 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 65) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit".**FIRST_PHASE**:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit".**FIRST_PHASE**:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found    at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:459)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:406)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.jpa.hibernateogm5.HibernateOGMPersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernateOGMPersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:87)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$900(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
>     ... 7 more
>
> 17:58:42,926 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation
>   ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NOTiFYwell.ear")]) -
>   failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found
>       Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found"}} 17:58:42,927
>   ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1)
>   WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "NOTiFYwell.ear" was rolled back
>   with the following failure message:  {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services"
>   => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found
>       Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found"}} 17:58:42,939
>   INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7)
>   WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name: NOTiFYwellJAR.jar)
>   in 10ms 17:58:42,942 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC
>   service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0208: Stopped subdeployment (runtime-name:
>   NOTiFYwellWAR.war) in 13ms 17:58:42,952 INFO 
>   [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028:
>   Stopped deployment NOTiFYwell.ear (runtime-name: NOTiFYwell.ear) in
>   25ms

The error:

> Provider org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found

Refers to class **OgmIntegrator** found in:

```
org/hibernate/ogm/service/impl/OgmIntegrator.class under /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/11.0.0.Final/libexec/modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/ogm/5.3/hibernate-ogm-core-5.3.0.Final.jar
```

Any ideas why this isn't being loaded? TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure out the problem, you need to use this:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.3" services="export" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb" slot="5.3" services="export" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

This exception

```
org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: org.hibernate:5.3
```

means that you are using **org.hibernate:5.3** instead of **org.hibernate.ogm:5.3**

The error might be in the jboss-deployment descriptor or in the MANIFEST.MF. Just make sure you are only using one or the other.

UPDATE: There was an error in the Hibernate website FAQ session, I updated it. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the EAR deployed.

It only deploys the EAR if I include a MANIFEST.MF in EAR's META-INF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.hibernate.ogm:5.3 services, org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb:5.3 services
```

and **remove** 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml'.

If I try and use a 'jboss-deployment-structure.xml' (empty MANIFEST):

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm" slot="5.3" services="export" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.ogm.mongodb" slot="5.3" services="export" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

It fails to deploy with the error I've had before:

> 17:31:53,892 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 30) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit".**FIRST_PHASE**:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.persistenceunit."NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit".**FIRST_PHASE**:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found    at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:640)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:137)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)  at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)    at
>   java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
>     at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:459)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:40)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:224)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:406)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernatePersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:199)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.jpa.hibernateogm5.HibernateOGMPersistenceProviderAdaptor.getBootstrap(HibernateOGMPersistenceProviderAdaptor.java:87)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$900(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:59)
>     at
>   org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PhaseOnePersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
>     ... 7 more
>
> 17:31:53,908 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYCTL0013: Operation
>   ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "NOTiFYwell.ear")]) -
>   failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
>   {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found
>       Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found"}} 17:31:53,909
>   ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 3)
>   WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "NOTiFYwell.ear" was rolled back
>   with the following failure message:  {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services"
>   => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"NOTiFYwell.ear/NOTiFYwellJAR.jar#NOTiFYwellMongoDBPersistenceUnit\".**FIRST_PHASE**"
>   => "java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found
>       Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider
>   org.hibernate.ogm.service.impl.OgmIntegrator not found"}}

Mapped an enity to my MongoDB table and was able to return a 'List' of Entities.

Had to ensure Collection's id type  was mapped as:

> @Id 
>   @Type(type = "objectid") 
>   private String id;